# Multi-bitrate/dynamic rate for progressive FLV playback

Tags: apache-flex, flash, dynamic, streaming, flv

Is there a way to get multi-bitrate playback working with progessive playback without having to download all versions of the file? People all coming up with all kinds of cool ways to make progressive feel like streaming. I wouldn't be surprised if there is also a hack for this. Any module names or reading resources that people in the know in this field can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, more of a hack really.
I hope you have small clips in mind, otherwise it might get pretty slow for big files.

How about you have audio in a separate file(either flv with no video encoded or just plain mp3) and then your flv.

You load your flv, you play make 'screengrabs' at runtime using [BitmapData's draw](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) method and store them in a Vector/Array and that should be it. You can play them back at dynamic speeds,

As for the mp3, you'll next the change the pitch. [Andre Michelle](http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/) has a great article about that.

Is the pricing the issue in not streaming flvs? [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) is opensource.